# Are there musical cryptograms for "Happy New Year"?

Tags: composition

Composers have created many clever ways to spell out words and names in their compositions. These are called "[musical cryptograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_cryptogram)"; the [B-A-C-H motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BACH_motif) perhaps being the most famous.

I'd like to say "Happy new year" musically in a similar way. Ideas?

---

Of interest to musical cryptogramists: [Musical cryptogram](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/60421/musical-cryptogram) (regarding Shostokovich's D-S-C-H)

Answer (score 1):

One (tortured) way to do it:

```
X: 1
T: Happy New Year
C: Aaron
K: none
L: 1/4
M: 3/4
B !pp!A x/8 e | ^d3 | =d e "RH"a ||
s: H A(PP) "E"=ipa:i | "NU" | Y E A(RH)
```

H = B (from German, as in B-A-C-H)
APP = A played ***pp***
Y = E (pronounced "EE")
Nu = D#/Eb (in the [Sottorio solfege system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Chromatic_variants))
Y = D ["French" encipherment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_cryptogram#French)
E
AR(H) = A  played with RH